# Trimming to the right of a character

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to trim to the right of a certain character in a text string.

Currently I am using

```
$string = "1500 pixels"
$string.Trim(" pixels")
```

This works fine and returns `1500` but if the last characters aren't `" pixels"` then it will fail. How do I trim to the right of `" "`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Split()` method can do this for you, it split a string into an array using a delimiter.

You split the string using space `" "` as the delimiter, then use `[0]` to return the first element of the array - which is `1500` in your example:

```
$string = "1500 pixels"
$string.Split(" ")[0]
```

And `[1]` to return the second element (`pixels`), if you also want to know this:

```
$string.Split(" ")[1]
```

Comment: and `$Left, $Right = $string.Split(" ")` if you're going to want both sides.

Answer (score 6):

[James C.'s helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42963897/45375) works well, but just to show **an alternative using the `-replace` operator**:

```
> '1500 pixels' -replace ' .*'  # short for: '1500 pixels' -replace ' .*', ''
1500
```

Regular expression `' .*'` matches the *first* space and everything that comes after (`.*`), and, due to the absence of a replacement string, replaces what was matched with the *empty* string, i.e., effectively *removes* the match.

---

In case you only want to trim from the *rightmost* space, [LotPings](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6811411/lotpings) offers this variation:

```
> '1500 pixels and more' -replace ' [^ ]*$'
1500 pixels and
```

`[^ ]*$` matches any sequence (`*`) of chars. that aren't a space char. (`[^ ]`) through the end of the string (`$`).